# {'message': 'Too Many Requests', 'error': 429} error

Tags: python, python-requests, reddit

I'm trying to request reddit "api" with requests module in python. But I'm getting this response:

```
{'message': 'Too Many Requests', 'error': 429}
```

Here is my code:

```
def main():
  import requests

  api = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json')
  data = api.content
  print(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Comment: What's the question? You are hitting the rate limits, implement `sleep` or error handling.

Comment: When a webservice has detected that a particular client, or request from a IP has reached its allowed threshold, it will return HTTP 429.

Answer (score 1):

You are hitting [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) which are often encountered when *user sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate limiting").*
For such error codes *[`Retry-After` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Retry-After) might be included in the  response indicating how long to wait before making a new request.* So you could implement a sleep logic like this.

```
>>> time.sleep(response.headers.get('Retry-After', <default>))
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `user-agent` to your requests

```
import requests
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; PPC Mac OS X 10_8_7 rv:5.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.31.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/533.31.5',
}

api = requests.get('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes.json',headers=headers)
print(api.content)
```